# Excel count number of duplicates in a row, ignoring blanks, and return boolean

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, duplicates, boolean

I have a row of random data in Excel like below:

```
    |  A  |  B  |   C   |  D  |   E   | F | G |
| 1 | see | saw | swing | see | slide |   |   |
```

How could I detect if there were duplicates in `row 1` and return a `1` if there were and a `0` if there were not, ignoring any blank cells in columns `F` and `G`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array formula works:

```
=OR(COUNTIF($A$1:$G$1,A1:G1)>1)
```

<sub>Array formulas are entered using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>** instead of regular <kbd>Enter</kbd></sub>

[image: checking for duplicates in row]

If `0` or `1` is needed, add 2 hyphens at the beginning of the formula:

```
=--OR(COUNTIF($A$1:$G$1,A1:G1)>1)
```

Comment: Both of these don't seem to work. Is the `;` a regional thing like the `,` in the UK?

Comment: Yep, it should be `,` . I edited the answer, as in most areas it's `,` , although I use `;`

Comment: What I can't workout, If I change the values in the cells to: `[blank2]2015/16 [blank2]2016/17 [blank2]2017/18 [blank2]2018/19 [blank2]2019/20 [blank2]2020/21`
Then it returns a `1` as opposed to a `0`. Is there something in the format of those values that would skew the formula?

Comment: I copy-pasted these values and for me it returns `0`. Did you enter the formula using Ctrl, Shift, Enter?

Comment: So when Is use Ctrl+Shift+Enter, it returns a `1` instead of a `0`. When I don't use Ctrl+Shift+Enter it returns a `0`. However when I do add a duplicate and don't use Ctrl+Shift+Enter, it still says `0`.

Comment: You must use Ctrl+Shift+Enter without doubt. But I don't know why do you get incorrect results. Are the cells `A1:G1` all formatted as *General* or *Text*? No *Custom* format?

Comment: Nope they're just *General*. Using Ctrl+Shift+Enter returns a `1` regardless of what the values are. My data set is: `[blank2]2015/16 [blank2]2016/17 [blank2]2017/18 [blank2]2018/19 [blank2]2019/20 [blank2]2020/21 [blank1]2015/16 [blank1]2016/17`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97141/discussion-between-zygd-and-barry-blade).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

`=(COUNTIF(A1:G1,A1)>1)*1`

Comment: This way you detect only if there are duplicates of `see`. You will need more formulas to detect other specific duplicates. I proposed an answer thinking that you need to know if there were *any* duplicates in that row.